# Pass information from remote service to application

Tags: android, browser, service

I created my own custom browser and I also have a background service that runs on startup.  These are not in the same package, they are two separate installs.  I want the service to be able to open my custom browser and launch a specific website in it at a specific time.  I am currently able to launch the custom browser from the service but I don't know how to pass the specified url to it.  Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I currently have it working now using something along the lines of this in my background service.

```
intent.putExtra("WebSite", "www.android.com")
```

then in my custom browser I put this in the onCreate() method

```
Intent sender = new Intent();
sender = getIntent();
String address = sender.getExtras().getString("WebSite");
```

I am getting the url then, but it is obviously force closing when I launch the app on my own instead of letting the remote service launch it because there is no intent for getIntent to get. I'm going to put a method in to check if there is an intent and if there is to launch it and if not skip. I think that should work. does anyone else have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First activity (thus your service):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.putExtra("website", "www.android.com");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Second activity (thus your browser:)

```
String website = "";
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
   website = bundle.getString("website");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I put that in my edit a little bit ago.  My problem is that I want the browser to be able to run independent of the service as well.  So if I put what you have in my onCreate method I will get a runtime exception because there is no intent to get

Comment: @michaelw2608 Sorry, I didn't see your edit. I changed my reply to answer your needs. This should work. (Did this on the flow though, not tested)